# change selected tab(li element ) color using php in a php file

Tags: php, html, css, tabs

I have a header.php file that implements `ul` `li` for showing a menu, where the menu items come from a database accessed using php. I have seen selected tab color change but most of them are done using javascript or css but in them list items are given in html.

Here is html `ul` item implementing menu:

```html
<body >
<!-- Start main menu BODY section -->
<center>
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
    <?php echo $show_menu;?>
</ul></center>
<!-- End main menu BODY section -->
</div>
```

And here is show menu php code:

```php
<?php
    $page_sql="SELECT * FROM na_links where sort_order in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) order by sort_order ASC limit 0,9";
    $page_q=mysql_query($page_sql);
    while($page_r=mysql_fetch_array($page_q))
    {       
            $page_id = $page_r['na_id'];
            $page_name = $page_r['na_menu'];
            if($page_id==1){ 
                                $show_footer_menu .= "<a href=\"home.php?page_id=$page_id\" class=\"fotterlink\">".$page_name."</a>|";
                                $show_menu .= "<li class=\"topmenu\"><a href=\"home.php?page_id=$page_id\" style=\"height:18px;line-height:18px;\"><span>". ucwords($page_name) . "</span></a></li> ";
                                                             }
            elseif($page_id==2 || $page_id==6) {
                $show_footer_menu .= "<a href=\"static_data_page.php?static_id=$page_id\" class=\"fotterlink\">".$page_name."</a>|";
            $show_menu .= "<li class=\"topmenu\"><a href=\"static_data_page.php?static_id=$page_id\" style=\"height:18px;line-height:18px;\">". ucwords($page_name) . "</a></li>";   }

            elseif($page_id==8) {
                $show_footer_menu .= "<a href=\"contact_us.php\" class=\"fotterlink\">".$page_name."</a>";
            $show_menu .= "<li class=\"topmenu\"><a href=\"contact_us.php\" style=\"height:18px;line-height:18px;\">". ucwords($page_name) . "</a></li>";    }
            elseif($page_id == 46) 
                { 
            $show_menu .="<li class=\"topmenu\"><a href=\"static_data_page.php?static_id=$page_id\" style=\"height:18px;line-height:18px;\" >" . ucwords($page_name) . "</a></li>"; 
                }                                                      
            else {
                $show_footer_menu .= "<a href=\"content.php?page_id=$page_id\" class=\"fotterlink\">".$page_name."</a>|";
            $show_menu .= "<li class=\"topmenu\"><a href=\"content.php?page_id=$page_id\" style=\"height:18px;line-height:18px;\">". ucwords($page_name) . "</a></li>";      }

    }
?>
<!------------------------------ End of menu---------------------------->
```

I tried to change the background color in show menu php id 1 style but, it doesn't changes it when selected but keeps that color changed.

```
 if($page_id==1){ 
 $show_menu .= "<li class=\"topmenu\"><a href=\"home.php?page_id=$page_id\" style=\"height:18px;line-height:18px background-color:blue;\"><span>". ucwords($page_name) . "</span></a></li> ";
```

Any help??

if i do it using JS, how do i get the class name from php as when i get get document.get element by class name (hbtn), JS function cannot find this class name

```
<script>
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("css3menu1");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("hbtn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>
```

here is classname added in php

```
$show_menu .= "<li class=\"topmenu hbtn\"><a href=\"content.php?page_id=$page_id\" style=\"height:18px;line-height:18px;\">". ucwords($page_name) . "</a></li>";
```

Comment: `$show_footer_menu` is not being used anywhere, you may want to use it in `$show_menu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more details about the application it's hard to give you a more specific answer.

As you have specified that you don't want to use JS to do this, it's probably worth checking the [superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). More specifically [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

If you `var_dump($_SERVER);` at the start of that script, you should see what the requested script is and can probably write a function that checks against it to apply some styling based on that.

Personally, I would probably aim towards doing it with JS and CSS but I also understand that this is not always a possibility. Just keep in mind that `$_SERVER` variables can be easily spoofed and you should try to avoid them if possible (particularly with anything business critical such as authorisation).

As you become more confident with PHP (or any server-side scripting) you should start to try and separate your view/presentation logic from your business logic.

I hope this helps, if not please let me know.

Comment: I am just going to avoid doing this using php. i'll try using JS and css.

Comment: let me know if you could help in this using JS,  @DazBaldwin

Comment: @Mehwish, I'll try and add an edit to my answer on my lunch break today. hopefully get you on the right track.